# mongodb - 2 geointersect queries with embedded documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called "sets" with hundreds of documents similar to this one :

```
{
"setNumber": "1",
"rectangles": [
    {
        "RecId" : 1,
        "RecType" : "A",
        "connectedTo" : [2,3],
         "title": "Nigeria",
         "geo": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [ 0 , 0 ] ,
                    [ 3 , 10 ] ,
                    [ 10 , 1 ] ,
                    [ 0 , 0  ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "RecId" : 2,
        "RecType" : "B",
        "title": "Europe",
        "geo": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
            [
                [ 45 , 45 ] ,
                [ -10 , 60 ] ,
                [ -10 , 40 ] ,
                [ 45 , 45  ]
            ]
        ]
        }
    },
    {
        "RecId" : 3,
        "RecType" : "B",
        "title": "North America",
        "geo": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [ -65 , 20 ] ,
                    [ -140 , 20 ] ,
                    [ -140 , 50 ] ,
                    [ -65, 50 ],
                    [ -65 , 20  ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "RecId" : 4,
        "RecType" : "A",
        "connectedTo" : [3],
        "title": "Brazil",
        "geo": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [ -30 , -30 ] ,
                    [ -100 , -30 ] ,
                    [ -100 , 0 ] ,
                    [ -30, 0 ],
                    [ -30 , -30  ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

Type A polygons are connected to one or multiple type B polygons.
I have been trying for hours to create the following query :

1. User submits 2 points coordinates, A and B.
2. GeoIntersect point A with all the "type A" polygons in the collection.
3. For each match, look at the type A "connectedTo" array and geoIntersect the connected type B polygons with point B.
4. Return the setNumber and the matching RecId pairs

for example,
 
point a = [3, 5] (geoIntersects with RecId = 1)
point b = [-80, 30] (geoIntersects with RecId = 3)
should return

```
{
"setNumber":"1",
"results": [[1,3]]
}
```

Any hint/ideas on how to implement this will be very welcome !

Thanks

Edit: I can modify the documents fields/data model at will if needed

Edit 2 following Neil comment :
this query output a specific subdocument

```
db.sets.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$rectangles"},{
        $match: {
            "rectangles.geo": {
                $geoIntersects: {
                    $geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [3, 5]}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {$project: {"rectangles.connectedTo": 1, "_id":0, "setNumber":1}}
    ])
```

the result is :

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "setNumber" : 1,
            "rectangles" : {
                            "RecId" : 1,
                "connectedTo" : [
                    2,
                    3
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: The current geospatial index implementation will not work with documents contained in an array in the way that you might expect. Much like any queries on elements in an array it is the actual "document" that is matched by the query and the response is not a "filter" of the array. So if "rec1" and "rec3" are actually part of the same "document" then that is what is returned in the result. It sounds as if you will only get what you need by using a separate collection for these rather than an array.

Comment: Hi Neil, see "Edit 2" in my question. I managed to do it but it is not ideal...

Comment: You cannot do that. Any Geo type query needs to be run as the **first** stage of the aggregation pipeline where it can actually use the index it requires. Once you have modified with `$unwind` it is no longer the original document and cannot use an index. You should get an error really. But the same applies. Put those documents in the array in a different collection, duplicating the other data if needed.